# Linux System Calls & Kernel Mode

Tags: security, system-calls

I understand that system calls exist to provide access to capabilities that are disallowed in user space, such as accessing a HDD using the `read()` system call. I also understand that these are abstracted by a user-mode layer in the form of library calls such as `fread()`, to provide compatibility across hardware.

So from the application developers point of view, we have *something* like;

```
//library    //syscall   //k_driver    //device_driver
fread()  ->  read()  ->  k_read()  ->  d_read()
```

My question is; what is stopping me inlining all the instructions in the `fread()` and `read()` functions directly into my program? The instructions are the same, so the CPU should behave in the same way? I have not tried it, but I assume that this does not work for some reason I am missing. Otherwise any application could get arbitrary kernel mode operation.

TL;DR: What allows system calls to 'enter' kernel mode that is not copy-able by an application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

System calls do not enter the kernel themselves. More precisely, for example the read function you call is still, as far as your application is concerned, a library call. What `read(2)` does internally is calling the actual system call using some interruption or the `syscall(2)` assembly instruction, depending on the CPU architecture and OS.

This is the only way for userland code to have privileged code to be executed, but it is an indirect way. The userland and kernel code execute in different contexts.

That means you cannot add the kernel source code to your userland code and expect it to do anything useful but crash. In particular, the kernel code has access to physical memory addresses required to interact with the hardware. Userland code is limited to access a virtual memory space that has not this capability. Also, the instructions userland code is allowed to execute is a subset of the ones the CPU support. Several I/O, interruption and virtualization related instructions are examples of prohibited code. They are known as privileged instructions and require to be in an lower ring or supervisor mode depending on the CPU architecture.

Comment: Ahh so it comes down to memory mapping, interesting. Something more to read into, thanks.

Comment: Not to mention privileged instructions that are forbidden when in user mode (answer updated).

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not clear on how the switch occurs, and why I cannot execute the 'switch instructions' manually: `<usermode execution><*switch*><kernelmode execution>` if I just inlined all that in say, a shellcode, why do I not get kernel-mode execution?

Comment: The switch occur by calling syscall(2) or equivalent. The issue is that switch is not linear, i.e. it is not your instructions that are executed following the switch but the instructions the operating system has registered for the specific system call number you called. Your instructions will be executed only after the system call has returned and you'll be then back in non privileged mode. That's why you have no way to have your code executed in kernel mode when running a modern OS, unless you write and install a kernel module or write yourself that operating system ...

Comment: @lynks, the old x86 method is to place the system call number and arguments in the proper register and stack locations, then call the `int 80` instruction.  You can do this part yourself directly if you wish.  The CPU implements the `int 80` hardware instruction by switching to kernel mode and jumping to the address of the kernel syscall handler, as it defined in the Interrupt descriptor table.  Once in kernel mode, the system has access to the memory and hardware needed to implement the call.

Comment: Ahh it is becoming clearer now. The only way to execute kernel mode instructions is via the interrupt descriptor table. So you would either have to write to the IDT, or write to the areas of memory that the IDT points to. Both of which are never mapped writable to a usermode process. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You could inline them. You can issue system calls directly through `syscall(2)`, but that soon gets messy. Note that the system call overhead (context switches back and forth, in-kernel checks, ...), not to mention the time the system call itself takes, makes your gain by inlining dissapear in the noise (if there is any gain, more code means cache isn't so useful, and performance suffers). Trust the libc/kernel folks to have studied the matter and done the inlining for you behind your back (in the relevant `*.h` file) if it really is a measurable gain.

Comment: I mean inlining the contents of `read()` also, surely this would not work, otherwise I could just stop at whatever point my program enters ring 0, and branch off to some malware.